# How to set minimum age using date validator of formvalidator.net?

Tags: jquery, jquery-form-validator

I am using [Jquery FormValidator](http://www.formvalidator.net/#date-validators) **birthdate** attribute.

But,

It has been set that it only allows past dates and dates that is not older than 120 years.

I just want one more validation, that is, it should also not allow age less than 18 yrs.

How could i acheive that ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the date validtator from [Date-Module](https://github.com/victorjonsson/jQuery-Form-Validator/blob/master/src/modules/date.js) and add a [custom validator](http://www.formvalidator.net/#custom-validators).

I just added the line `var requiredAge = 18;` and added the var to the validation.

https://jsfiddle.net/03ehx9ns/

```js
$.validate({
  modules : 'date'
});

$.formUtils.addValidator({
  name : 'older18',
  validatorFunction : function(val, $el, conf) {
   var requiredAge = 18;
   var dateFormat = 'yyyy-mm-dd';
    if($el.valAttr('format')) {
      dateFormat = $el.valAttr('format');
    }
    else if(typeof conf.dateFormat !== 'undefined') {
      dateFormat = conf.dateFormat;
    }

    var inputDate = $.formUtils.parseDate(val, dateFormat);
    if (!inputDate) {
      return false;
    }

    var d = new Date();
    var currentYear = d.getFullYear();
    var year = inputDate[0];
    var month = inputDate[1];
    var day = inputDate[2];

    if (year === currentYear - requiredAge) {
      var currentMonth = d.getMonth() + 1;
      if (month === currentMonth) {
        var currentDay = d.getDate();
        return day <= currentDay;
      }
      else {
        return month < currentMonth;
      }
    }
    else {
      return year < currentYear - requiredAge && year > (currentYear - 124); // we can not live for ever yet...
    }
  },
  errorMessage : 'You need to be older then 18',
  errorMessageKey: 'badDate'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.3.26/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>

<form action="" id="date-form">
    <p>
      Birth date
      <input name="..." data-validation="older18" 
   data-validation-help="yyyy-mm-dd (Not allowing dates in...">
    </p>
    <p>
      Time
      <input name="" data-validation="time" data-validation-help="HH:mm">
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="submit">
    </p>
  </form>
```

Comment: `errorMessage` is not triggered if age is provided less then 18